# Given $\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^l, k+l=n, A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ product of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R}^l$

Tags: real-analysis

Why is it not necessarily true that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as the product of two subsets $X \subset \mathbb{R}^k, Y \subset \mathbb{R}^l$. It seems that it should be possible for each point in A, the first k coordinates are in $\mathbb{R}^k$, given such a point you can create the set in $\mathbb{R}^l$ that contains all the points such that all the points given the first coordinates belong to A. Then taking the Union over all the points in $\mathbb{R}^k$, it seems to me like you could represent A this way. What is wrong with this argumentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $A_1\subset \mathbb R^k$ and $A_2\subseteq \mathbb R^l$, then if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)\in A_1\times A_2$ then $(a,d)$ and $(c,b)\in A_1\times A_2$.

This is not true for a general subset $\mathbb R^{k}\times\mathbb R^{l}$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:
Assume $A = \{(1, 2), (2, 3)\}$ and $k = l = 1$ , so $A$ cannot be written as the product of two subsets.